# Task list - Timeline is not updated (views)

Tags: 2013, list-view, task-list, timeline

I have a task list and a timeline. When I create views to sort the list, the timeline is not updated accordingly. Do you have any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The Timeline for a List is a simple representation of Tasks based on Dates. And it has pointers of Today, Task Dates, Start and Finish etc.

So literally, it will have **no effect based on List view changes (Sorted/Filtered in your case)**

Additionally, 
[image]

Comment: Why would anyone like to use timelines then? If I create a view with the filter, show only "wer2323r" (from your image). Then I do not want to see timelines for other tasks.

Comment: Filter works for sure... but not the sorting.... filter limits the no. Of items but sorting just arranges them.. and so Timeline doesn’t have impact because of sorting

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, please explain how i can filter between "wer2323r" and  "qwqwdqwd" and only get the matching timeline.

Comment: It does not work with filters. I still see the same number of timelines. Please describe how you do.

Comment: Aah sorry, I was wrong.. This timeline doesn't get updated even with filtering.. What you are trying achieve is not possible using out of the box but a customized solution may work here.. Refer : https://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html